# Buddypress Fake (non-bot) Users

Tags: buddypress, spam, user-registration

BuddyPress Newbie question:

I have a brand new site running WP 3.3.1 and BP 1.5. Even before launch I am plagued with numerous fake users every day. I don't think they are bots, because I have a math question at registration, and email activation enabled. They register, usually with a gmail address, and then activate and post updates containing spam links of all sorts.

I haven't been able to find any real ideas on how to stop non-bot spammers, and have pretty much given up on an automated solution. Barring that, is there a way to hold new users for admin approval and prevent them from posting until they are approved?

Any solutions are greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Diana

Comment: Have you tried Akismet and/or reCAPTCHA?

Comment: Both. The issue is not comments or bots... I'm exploring a new user registration approval plugin. May have to write it myself, it seems.

Comment: Have tried Sabre? - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sabre/

Comment: Thanks. At least for now, sabre seems a bit overkill for my needs, although I'll keep it in queue for later. I actually solved the problem (for now) with [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-approve-user/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-approve-user/)

Answer (score 1):

Fake registerion to buddypress is a real pain in the !@$ (pardon my french).
I've tried math question, captch, sabre and other plugins but none of them seem to work.

So far, only [WangGuard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wangguard/) did the trick. It won't give you full protection against those registrations but it's the most efficient tool I've found against them.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that they bypass the activation link that's sent to their email by putting in their own activation key in the URL. I found a blog about it, I can't seem to find it again.